# PHP session only working on certain pages

Tags: php, session-variables

I am using PHP on inmotion hosting. On my login page, I set a few session variables that I will later use on other pages. The problem is some pages cant access the session variables, while others can't I'm using the same code on both pages, so it doesn't really make any sense why it works on some pages but not others.

Just to test it out I used on both pages after logging in

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

On one page it works as expected and lists my variables on the other it just lists an empty array

Any ideas what could be going on?
Just to make sure it wasn't something else on the page, I commented out all my other code on both pages, and they both have the same permissions.

Comment: There are a LOT of questions about this on stackoverflow. Please look up similar questions and see if the answers to these hold your solution. If you've already checked them all, please show us which topics/questions/answers you've looked at, so we know not to recommend things you've already checked. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin I've looked at a lot of them, most of them just suggest adding session_start(); at the beginning of the PHP file which I have or permission issues. I've checked the session cookie is being written on my local machine, and the variable are being written on the server and I can access them on certain pages, but not others.

Comment: @Martin I did some additional testing and moved the effected file into a folder and it works fine there, but anything in the root of the website cannot access the session. Any Ideas?

Comment: I finally figured it out! For somereason all the subfolders are using a different php.ini folder as the files in my root folder of the website, so the write path was different from the others.